# What are some extra (mustahab) zikrs to use in different parts of an obligatory prayer?

Tags: salat, wajib, dhikr, mustahab

I've been wondering how one can lengthen their prayer -in order to remain more in praying condition- by using extra zikrs in ruku', sijdah, tashahhud, salaam and so on? I've heard that any prayer in praise of Allah is permissible in sijdah and ruku. I'd be glad to know if this is true, and if so, what are some more common/accepted suggestions. What about tashahhud and salaam, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes any prayer in praise are permissible. Those are some of prayer that the prophet Mohamed usually used in Salah 
 
1- **DOUA ISTIFTAH** after TAKBIRET AL IHRAM, (after you said alahou akbar and start the prayer and before you start el FATIHA)
Oh God  separate between me and my sins as you  separated between the east and west,
Oh God cleans me of my sins as white clothes are cleaned from pollution
Oh God, wash me from, my sins with water, snow, cold

You can also say
And I turned my face to Him Who created the skies and the earth upright, and I am not one of the idolaters
My prayer and my life and my dying are for the God, no other God with him, and so I ordered and I am one of the Muslims
Oh Allah, You are the King and no God but you
You are my Lord and I am your servant wronged myself and acknowledged my sin, so forgive me all my sins. No one forgive sins except You
And guide me to the best of ethics. No one guide me except you
And separate me from immorality No one separate me except you
Oh god I obey you, all good is between your hands and evil is not you. I am what I am with your guidance and my life is for you. You are the greatest and above all. I ask your Forgiveness and I will not come back to my sins

2- **DOUA ROUKOU**
Hallelujah great Lord and thank you for what you gave me (subhana rabi al adim wabihamdih)
then you say
God for you I Knelt down, I believe in you, for you converted to Islam. You are my God.
Overawe for you my Hearing, my Sight, my Cerebral, my skeleton and what I can and my feet for the god of us all

3- **DOUA after ROUKOU and before SOUJOUd** (when you stand up)
God listen to who tanks him - Our Lord! For you the thanking or
God listen to who tanks him - Our Lord! For you much good thanking like our God wants

4-**DOUA SOUJOUD** (here where the person can be closest to the GOD) so you can use doua that I will write or whatever doua you want
Hallelujah my Lord who is above everything (subhana rabi al alawabihamdih)
Or Hallelujah my Lord who is above everything and thank you for what you gave me (you repeatit many times)
Oh God for you I Worship, in you I believe, for you I Converted to Islam, you are my Lord. Prostrated my face to who created it and make it beautiful. The lord that gave me Sight and hearing. Hallelujah my Lord the creator
Oh God, make light in my heart, make light in my tongue, make light in my eyes, make light in my ears, make light underneath me, make light above me, make light at my right, make light at my left
Og God, forgive me

Reference page 
 http://www.saaid.net/mktarat/ramadan/343.htm

[http://mawdoo3.com](http://mawdoo3.com/%D8%AF%D8%B9%D8%A7%D8%A1_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%A9)

Comment: Thanks a million. You were of great help. May god be pleased with you. (will be back to upvote your answer once I earn a minimum of 15!)